# C# Can't insert event to Google Calendar using API

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

when I'm trying to insert a new event to my calendar I recive error:

> Not Found [404]
>   Errors [Message[Not Found] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]]

I figured out that I have no access to a diffrent callendar than primary.

Here is my code:

```
Event newEvent = new Event()
{
    Summary = ee[0],
    Start = new EventDateTime()
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Parse(ee[2] + "T" + ee[3] + ":00+02:00")
    },
    End=new EventDateTime()
    {
        DateTime=DateTime.Parse(ee[4] + "T" + ee[5] + ":00+02:00")
    },
    Location=ee[2],
};
EventsResource.InsertRequest ins = service.Events.Insert(newEvent, nazwa_cal);
Event doins = ins.Execute();
Console.WriteLine("Event created: {0}", doins.HtmlLink);
```

where `cal_name` is the name of my calendar I want to insert event to.

If I change the name to `"primary"` it works perfecty.

I followed this instructions but nothing changed: [LINK](https://github.com/extrabacon/google-oauth-jwt/issues/8#issuecomment-40858290)

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `id` instead of the name and check if this will work in your case.

First, get the Id of the calendar in where you want to insert your event by using the [`CalendarList: list`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list#try-it)

GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?maxResults=5&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

[image]

Then you can now [insert to this event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#try-it) by using its Id.

POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/google.comXXXXXXXXXX9778%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
{
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2016-10-15T8:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Manila"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2016-10-15T6:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Asia/Manila"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@adjuremods

Thank You very much for your answer. I follwed it and chose from the list field `id` instead of `summary`. It works perfect!